# Reading position indicator - Chrome issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using this code: [LINK](http://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/towxF) - it indicates reading position in a horizontal way.

I want to adapt this script to get not whole document height, but only one of my div's height. This is the original function:

```
var getMax = function(){
return $(document).height() - $(window).height();
}
```

I try to replace above code with this:

```
var getMax = function(){
var content = $("#content");
return content.height();
}
```

Eveything in Firefox works fine, but in Chrome my horizonal bar fills immediately. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this changing your `$(document).ready(fn)` in `$(window).load(fn)` event.

- `ready` is fired when the DOM is fully loaded, in this case your element in Chrome could not be ready or not fully loaded yet
- `load` ,instead, assure you that all the assets in the page are loaded so you can safetly do operation on elements (in your case calculate the height).
  [This demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyPvrx) works in Firefox and Chrome.

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> The `load` event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

[Here](https://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/) an article that explain a little more in depth the difference between `ready` and `load` event.